# Read variable until output is greater than a certain Value in BASH

Tags: linux, bash

I have a command that has a numeric output, but sometimes, because of an error over which I have no control whatsoever, the output value is below 100.
What I need is to read this output, and only continue if the output is greater than 100. The problem is that the "until loop" only reads the variable once. Even though the variable changes over time, the until loop only uses the output from the first variable reading.
Is there some way in which I can force it to read the command output many times, until the right value is found?

```
VARIABLE=$(command)

until [  ${VARIABLE} -gt 100 ]; do
  sleep 0.1
done

echo "$(VARIABLE)"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No fancy stuff needed, you just need to put the command in the loop and then have the loop condition as the condition you actually want to loop on.

```
while [[ "$variable" -le 100 ]];do 
    variable=$(command) 
    sleep 0.1 
done
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I don't know how I did not think of it, especially because now I realize that I've used it before.

Answer (score 5):

You only run `command` once and then loop forever on the output you got from that single invocation.  Presumably, what you want is to run the command multiple times, examining the result after each invocation.

```
while true; do
    variable=$(command)    # avoid uppercase variable names
    ((variable > 100)) && break
    sleep 0.1
done
echo "$variable"           # always quoting is good form
```

The `((...))` arithmetic evaluation facility is Bash only.  If you need your script to be POSIX-compatible (i.e. run under any modern variant of `sh`) you have to use slightly more complex constructs (`[ "$variable" -gt 100 ]` should work all the way back to classic Bourne shell, assuming `variable` always contains a number).